# Use a multilevel logistic regression and cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, cross-validation, multilevel-analysis, perceptron

I want to use a multilevel logistic regression for a double purpose, estimating the value of coefficients to explain a phenomenon. At the same time, I want to split the data through cross-validation for prediction. 
My question is whether is it combinable a partition in the dataset for prediction and the use of mixed linear models? Additionally,  I want to try other algorithms that implement non-linear solutions, is it possible to use a mixed-level model in a multilayer perceptron, decision tree, etc?

Comment: See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167715217300895 and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169743918304362. There is an R package caled glmertree - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmertree/vignettes/glmertree.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the suggestion of Erik Ruzek above:

**`R`** package **`glmertree`** allows for fitting decision trees to multilevel and longitudinal data (which would otherwise be modeled with a mixed-effects model).

It allows for specifying a random effects structure, and partitions the dataset into subgroups using level-I, or higher-level, predictors.

Further info can be found in the package vignette (link in comment of E.R. above), or:

Fokkema, M., Smits, N., Zeileis, A., Hothorn, T., & Kelderman, H. (2018). Detecting treatment-subgroup interactions in clustered data with generalized linear mixed-effects model trees. Behavior research methods, 50(5), 2016-2034. https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-017-0971-x

Fokkema, M., Edbrooke-Childs, J., & Wolpert, M. (2021). Generalized linear mixed-model (GLMM) trees: A flexible decision-tree method for multilevel and longitudinal data. Psychotherapy Research, 31(3), 329-341. https://doi.org/10.1080/10503307.2020.1785037